# Is there a way to log which method in controller or service made the query in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

[log photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p85vb.png)

I need to log the following together when a method from a service is called:

- class name
- method name
- method type
- parameter's used
- query used by method
- controller link (optional, will figure out later)

As you can see in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p85vb.png) I am able to do it but the query is logged separately. Is there a way to append the query together?

I put these in application.properties to log SQL queries:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

To log the other details I use an aspect (AOP):

```
@After("execution(* com.example.srs.student.StudentService.*(..))")
    public void log(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();

        Method currentMethod = signature.getMethod();
        String className = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName();
        String methodName = currentMethod.getName();
        String methodType = currentMethod.getReturnType().toString();
        Parameter[] parameters = currentMethod.getParameters();
        ArrayList<String> parameterList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Parameter parameter : parameters) {
            parameterList.add(parameter.getType().getTypeName() + " - " + parameter.getName());
            //parameterList2.add(parameter.toString());
        }

        System.out.println(className + ", " + methodName + ", " + methodType + ", "
                + parameterList.toString());

        logger.info(joinPoint.getSignature().toString() + " ENNNDDDD");

    }
```

Comment: Take a look at tracing frameworks like Spring Cloud Sleuth (https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-sleuth)

Comment: I suspect it may be slightly difficult since your aspect intercepts calls to the service. When the service is invoked it knows nothing about the query. The query is created by some other code (Hibernate) at some other point in time.
One thing that may be worth looking into is to intercept both the service and the query creation saving information someplace and, when both pieces of information are present, log the message. Do remember threading.